# WinJs Copy to clipboard for Windows Phone

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, winjs

I am trying to implement copy text to clipboard on click of a button in windows phone 8 app but official [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard) says `Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard` is not supported on windows phone. Is there any other alternatives for windows phone?

`Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard` is undefined in following codes.

```
var dataPackage = new Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataPackage();
dataPackage.setText('Text to be copied to clipboard');
Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.setContent(dataPackage);
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that you already know by now, but it is not supported in Windows Phone 8 (As you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br205867)). Microsoft has included it in Windows 10 mobile.

If you're targetting both mobile OS, you can check if Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard exists before trying to do anything avoiding crashes.